# EXCEL VBA Count time

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have these data from column A to D.
I want to calculate **TOTAL HOURS RENDERED** for each name with has the same **END TIME PERIOD** as shown in the expected output.

```
Name    Date        End Time Period Hours Rendered
Mark    7/1/2019    7/15/2019       2
Mark    7/2/2019    7/15/2019       2
Mark    7/3/2019    7/15/2019       3
Mark    7/17/2019   7/30/2019       4
Mark    7/28/2019   7/30/2019       2
John    7/1/2019    7/15/2019       4
John    7/2/2019    7/15/2019       3
John    7/3/2019    7/15/2019       2
John    7/17/2019   7/30/2019       3
John    7/28/2019   7/30/2019       4
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT on the other worksheet:

```
Name    7/15/2019   7/30/2019
Mark    7           6
John    9           7
```

Comment: Please include the code you are using to solve this in your question and explain what problems you are having with it.

Comment: hello @braX, thank you so much for the response.  but  i am so sorry but I am very new to vba and I want to somehow automate the process of getting the total hours. :(

Comment: Well, what research have you done?

Comment: https://www.contextures.com/CreatePivotTable.html

Comment: thank you so much braX for all of the responds. I somehow managed to achieved it using Pivot as what you recommended. :D :D That was cool.

Comment: For the Vba version of it, I will still have to research for it :( but all in all I got the solution i wanted using pivot. Hopefully you can help me again with the vba. Thank you so much @braX

Comment: https://powerspreadsheets.com/vba-create-pivot-table/